# delphi prototype pattern

Tags: delphi, design-patterns, delphi-2007, prototype-pattern

I was wondering, is there anything in the RTTI of Delphi that will do the same as MemberwiseClone does in C# for the simple implementation of the prototype pattern.
I saw some Delphi implementations of this pattern where a new object is being created (TMyObject.Create) and it's properties assigned with values from the prototyping object. I might be wrong, but I don't see the benefit of the pattern if we the objects are created in that same basic manner.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing built in that will perform a deep-clone for you.  I'm sure you could write a deep-clone based on the new RTTI, but I'd expect it to be a non-trivial amount of work.

If you were dealing with simple enough types it would work fine, but you could easily run into serious challenges.  For example, off the top of my head:

- Some groups of objects need to be created in a specific order.
- Some members of a class should not be cloned, e.g. reference counts. How do you recognise those with RTTI?
- How do you deal with singletons?
- What about any extrinsic references that need to be set up? Suppose you clone an object that is normally created by a factory. If that factory holds a reference to the objects it creates then going behind its back may break your design.

You could implement your prototype pattern by defining a basic `Clone()` method which uses RTTI for simple types and then you have to override it for anything more complex. Personally though, I'd inherit from `TPersistent` and make my `Clone()` method based on `Assign`.

Comment: What can I do if I'm using D2007? I suppose the Clone() is not available in 2007 version?

Comment: @elector Clone is the function that you write yourself. That's really the essence of Prototype. If you had a more up-to-date Delphi then RTTI could help but on 2007 you'll certainly have to do it yourself.

Comment: Or you suggest the Assign for the TPersistent for D2007? Would that be a good Prototype pattern implementation example?
edit: I just saw your answer on my previous question. Thank you

Comment: @elector I'd say that `TPersistent.Assign` could be used to implement Prototype. However, it's not true Prototype because it's main use is to facilitate copying of data between objects of different but related types.

Comment: From a lean OOP view I would say if that factory holds a reference to the objects it creates, then it does 'too much' (single responsibility principle) - in real life, if it is implemented like this, it could also offer a method to add these externally created objects to the reference list :)

Comment: The Singleton constructor is (should be) private - so there is no way to create another instance from the outside...

Answer (score 9):

[Object.MemberwiseClone Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) makes a **shallow** copy of the object following some very simple rules and taking advantage of how the .NET garbage collector works.

- References are simply copied. This includes strings and references to any `object`.
- Value types are bit-copied (identical clones are made).

The part about the value types can easily be duplicated with Delphi. Duplicating the reference-type behavior with Delphi, while technically easy, will not provide the expected result: Delphi code is expected to `.free` the objects it creates, and it uses a `owner-owned` paradigm to make sure that happens. The usual pattern is to free objects created by the owner-object from the destructor. If you make a shalow-copy of the object, this results in failure. Here's an example:

- Object A owns a reference to object B.
- We create object C as a shallow copy of object A. Object C now contains a reference to object B.
- We free object A: `A.Free;`
- We free object B: `B.Free;` - this automatically calls `B.Free`, but unfortunately B was already freed when we freed A!

We could attempt a `deep-copy`, as David suggests, but that poses some equally difficult problems:

- Not all objects should be copied, for example because they encapsulate references to real-world resources (example: TFileStream).
- Some other objects can't be deep-copied because they're in essance Singletons. And there's no universal way of saying "This object is a Singleton, do a plain reference copy, don't do a deep copy". Example: Do we copy `Application`?
- If you do a deep copy you might have circular-references, you need to take care of those. That's not trivial, and you start the copy from an item in a collection, you might find yourself back to the parent of your collection, ie: not exactly the expected result.
- Indiscriminate deep-coping might take up unexpected amounts of memory and result in unexpected memory leaks. Think about the collection -> item -> copy item example again, where you end up with a copy of the "item", but the whole COLLECTION was copied because of unexpected back-links.

Putting this all together we can only reach one conclusion: We can't have a general purpose, Delphi equivalent of `MemberwiseClone`. We can have a partial look-alike for simpler objects with uncomplicated interactions, but that's not nearly as appealing!

Comment: We'll let's assume that we are talking about a specific use of the prototype pattern, not a generic one. We need to deep copy a custom, but known, object. I guess the purpose of this pattern to speed up the creation of many objects, right? And we know what objects these will be. With all this in mind, what would be a good solution in Delphi? Using memory streams, serialization...? And not using published properties in the prototyping object.

Comment: @elector, my Delphi 7 objects that need to get cloned actually offer a `Duplicate` method that returns a copy of the object; The `Duplicate` method is most often hand-implemented (doing field-by-field assignments) but I've got some implementations that rely on some streaming code. The streaming code is itself hand-written (field-by-field), my `Duplicate` only uses streaming because of my laziness: the field-by-field hand-copy would be faster.

Comment: With a field by field assignment method, does the prototype pattern make sense? Do we get a faster creation of a large number of objects? I guess the streaming code wouldn't make the creation of objects faster?

Comment: @elector, define *fast*. It takes fewer lines of code to make the clone once you've got the cloning code written; But *speed* and *prototyping* don't mix well: Prototype code is expected to be written fast, not executed fast. The `.NET` method that sparked all this isn't going to be particularly fast, since it most likely uses reflection to perform it's duties.

Answer (score 4):

There’s a way to perform a deep-copy (clone) of an object in Delphi. It works for the latest versions of Delphi (2010 and above). See the code snipped below...it’s actually quite simple and you don't need external libraries. You can find more information here: http://www.yanniel.info/2012/02/deep-copy-clone-object-delphi.html

```
function DeepCopy(aValue: TObject): TObject;
var
  MarshalObj: TJSONMarshal;
  UnMarshalObj: TJSONUnMarshal;
  JSONValue: TJSONValue;
begin
  Result:= nil;
  MarshalObj := TJSONMarshal.Create;
  UnMarshalObj := TJSONUnMarshal.Create;
  try
    JSONValue := MarshalObj.Marshal(aValue);
    try
      if Assigned(JSONValue) then
        Result:= UnMarshalObj.Unmarshal(JSONValue);
    finally
      JSONValue.Free;
    end;
  finally
    MarshalObj.Free;
    UnMarshalObj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: nice! But I guess it will not work if the object contains a collection which has circular object references?

Comment: It does work with collections. I tested it with an abject containing a generic TList<SomeTypeHere> and other object fields. It worked!

Comment: This throws the error "Internal: Type tkPointer is not currently supported", I am on XE and have a complex object to deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something similar to this: http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/source/browse/trunk/Library/src/Extensions/DeHL.Cloning.pas

It will only work on D2010 and up (requires extended RTTI).

Comment: Thank you this is a good resource but I made a mistake not mentioning in my question that I use D2007.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a somewhat generic [component cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442234/enumerating-published-properties-and-subproperties-in-delphi) answer a while back that might be useful, although it's not the equivalent of `MemberWiseClone`. It works in Delphi as far back as D5, I believe, and I'm sure it works in D2007.